# commenting on a app from rail girls

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is what im trying to accomplish.
http://guides.railsgirls.com/commenting/

i followed the steps but i get this error message.

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in IdeasController#show
unknown attribute: idea_id

```
  @idea = Idea.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @idea.comments.all
  **@comment = @idea.comments.build**
end
```

app/controllers/ideas_controller.rb:69:in `set_idea'

Comment: i have "belongs_to :idea" in the comment model. What code should i include?

Comment: this is the link to github https://github.com/arrayslayer21/selfbook

Comment: thats my link. which includes all files

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you included (a lot) more of your code, but based on what you've said it sounds as though the Comment model does not have a "belongs_to :Idea" and, possibly, the idea_id integer field may be missing from the migration itself.

Comment: i have "belongs_to :idea" in the comment model. What code should i include?

Comment: Do you have an idea_id of type integer in the Comments table? (double check the migrations)

Comment: class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :user_name
      t.text :body
      t.integer :idea_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end